# Add setgid bit on mounted NFS share

Tags: permissions, mount, nfs

I'd like to mount an NFS share enabling the setgid bit on the mounted folder. Is this possible in some way?

I tried first creating the mounted folder with the setgid bit:

```
mkdir --mode=u+wrx,g+wrxs,o+rx,o-w /mnt_gid
```

But as soon as I mount the nfs share with this fstab line:

```
remotehost.org:/myfolder /mnt_gid nfs4 _netdev,nodev 1 2
```

permissions change and the `s` bit on the group is removed.